# opengl es texture atlas for text

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, freetype

I need help on understanding the workflow for rendering text in opengl es using a texture atlas. This is for an iphone game.

I've read this already:

[Is there a decent OpenGL text drawing library for the iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512258/is-there-a-decent-opengl-text-drawing-library-for-the-iphone-sdk)

What tools do I use to generate the texture atlas image? Do I need freetype for this part? What file format should the image be?

In my iphone code...besides the texture atlas image, what else do I need to correctly render the text? Does freetype need to be included in my iphone source code? Am I generating an XML file with the glyph data as it relates to my texture atlas so that I don't have to load freetype into my iphone source code?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ready solutions in open-source engines.

I use .fnt format. It has texture atlas with prerendered chars and configuration file with mapping info.

For example it is integrated in Cocos2d:

- [CCLabelBMFont](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/blob/release-1.1-beta/cocos2d/CCLabelBMFont.m) - usage of .fnt fonts
- [GlyphDesigner.app](http://glyphdesigner.71squared.com/) - font creation tool (there is also free
  [Hiero tool](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/demos/hiero.jnlp), but it's buggy and simple)