# how can I render text in opengl es for user score

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a decent OpenGL text drawing library for the iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512258/is-there-a-decent-opengl-text-drawing-library-for-the-iphone-sdk)

I want to render text for my game score I use Texture2D as given below but I get only a white box instead of text

```
Texture2D*  _textures = [[Texture2D alloc] initWithString:@"hedsfdsdssfsffsdsfllo"   dimensions:CGSizeMake(200, 200) alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:30];
[_textures drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100)];
glColor4f(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
```

any help please

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it may help you but its worth a look.

[Is there a decent OpenGL text drawing library for the iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512258/is-there-a-decent-opengl-text-drawing-library-for-the-iphone-sdk)